# C++ Segmentation fault when trying to print linked list node string

Tags: c++, class, templates, fault

I'm creating a linked list-based stack and i'm using class templates. I want to define the `head` node of the stack via user input and then print it, however I am receiving a segmentation fault and am quite lost at working out why.

`TowerHanoi.cpp` uses the below function which creates a string and then tries to store it in a node, which is then stored in the stack using `push()`, which adds it to the '`head`' node of the Linked List. Upon attempting to print the head node of the Linked List i receive a segmentation fault:

`rod[]` refers to an array of LStack objects, which contains the Linked List and member functions that query and modify the Linked List.

```
    void TowerHanoi::set_Discs(size_t disc) {
    node<string>* temp= new node<string>();

    while (disc != 0) {
        string tmp_str;

        for (size_t i=0; i<disc; i++) {
            tmp_str.append("x");

        }
        disc--;
    temp->set_data(tmp_str);
    rod[0].push(temp);

    node<string>* tmp_node1 = rod[0].top();
    cout << "test: " + tmp_node1->data() << endl;
    }
}
```

LStack.template contains the definition for `'push()'`:

```
    namespace oreilly_A2 {

    template <typename Item>
    LStack<Item>::LStack() {
        list = new LinkedList<Item>();
    }


    //push
    template <typename Item>
    void LStack<Item>::push(Item* head_in) {
        list->addToHead(head_in);
        used++;
    }


    //top
    template <typename Item>
    Item* LStack<Item>::top() {
        return list->list_getHead();
    }
```

LinkedList.template initializes the `head` node in the constructor and contains the `addToHead(Item* entry)` function:

```
namespace oreilly_A2 {

    template <typename Item>
    LinkedList<Item>::LinkedList() { //constructor initializing nodes
        head= new node<std::string>();
        tail= new node<std::string>();
        current= new node<std::string>();

    }


    template <typename Item>
    void LinkedList<Item>::addToHead(Item* entry) {
        Item* temp = head;
        head = entry;
        head->set_link(temp);
    }
```

Node.template initializes `next` and `previous` node to NULL and contains the `set_data()` function:

```
namespace oreilly_A2 {


    template <typename Item>
    node<Item>::node() {
        next= NULL;
        previous= NULL;
    }

    template <typename Item>
    void node<Item>::set_data(Item new_data){
            word = new_data;
    }

template <typename Item>
Item node<Item>::data() const {  //return the word
        return word;
}
```

Comment: Please try to use a debugger to catch the crash, and in doing so narrow down the code to the location of the crash (and related code and context). There might also be issues regarding [the rules of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Well, did you already locate the exact source with the debugger?

Comment: what is `rod`? how you have defined it ?

Comment: Did you really only want to create one item (`temp`) and push the same item multiple times? Your stack implementation doesn't support that.

Comment: rod is an LStack object HadeS. Dark, I guess i should have created another temporary node at the addToHead function which creates a copy of temp with the new data and stores that?

Comment: Could you please reduce this to a minimal, complete, verifiable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, I hope my post is in a better state now. I have tested getting the program to print 'temp's string data which works, so something in the functionality of 'push()' is not working. I've attempted to use the GDB debugger in Cygwin and i'm trying to learn how to use it properly but its been more confusing than helpful so far. I will need to keep researching.

Answer (score 0):

In your `LinkedList<Item>::addToHead` function, which is called by `LStack<Item>::push`, it uses the passed in `node` and puts it into the linked list by setting its `next` pointer to the head of the list. This means that the passed in node is now part of the list.

When your `set_discs` function loops around again, it changes the value of `temp` and again pushes it onto the stack. But the node pointed to by `temp` is already on the stack! This means that it will end up pointing to itself, which is definitely going to cause some issues.

One way you might be tempted to fix this is to allocate a new object for `temp` each time round the loop, but that means that it is up to the user of a `LinkedList` to know that he has to allocate new items each time.

A better way is to consider that someone using a `LinkedList` or `LStack` shouldn't need to know how it is stored, so they don't need to interact with a `node` at all. Consider changing your methods of `LinkedList` and `LStack` to just take an `Item` reference. They can then construct their own node to store the data. Something like:

```
template <typename Item>
void LinkedList<Item>::addToHead(Item &entry) {
    node<Item>* temp = head;
    head = new node<Item>;
    head->set_date(Item);
    head->set_link(temp);
}
```

Similarly, change your `LStack` to just take an `Item &` and pass it through to the `LinkedList`

Then make your `rod` as an array (or whatever collection it is) of `LStack<string>`, rather than what you have now, which I suspect is an array of `LStack<node<string>>`.

You will then not need to do any allocation in your main loop, just pass a normal `std::string` (`tmp_string` will do as it is) to the `push` function.

One more thing, unless you are doing this to learn about making linked lists (or for a class), consider just using the stl classes, such as `std::stack`. In general it is much better to use the library classes than roll your own, unless there is a good reason (like learning).

Comment: Yeah I altered it to, as a test, just make one string (no while-loop), pass the string to list->addToHead() which passes the string to the head node. I also modified it to have your suggestion for addToHead() but I'm still getting the segmentation fault! I'm losing my mind..